# In which scenario would one use another matrix than the identity matrix for finding eigenvalues?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, linear-algebra, covariance

The `scipy.linalg.eigh` function can take two matrices as arguments: first the matrix `a`, of which we will find eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but also the matrix `b`, which is optional and chosen as the identity matrix in case it is left blank.
In what scenario would someone like to use this `b` matrix?

Some more context: I am trying to use xdawn covariances from the pyRiemann package. This uses the `scipy.linalg.eigh` function with a covariance matrix `a` and a baseline covariance matrix `b`. You can find the implementation [here](https://github.com/pyRiemann/pyRiemann/blob/master/pyriemann/spatialfilters.py). This yields an error, as the `b` matrix in my case is not positive definitive and thus not useable in the `scipy.linalg.eigh` function. Removing this matrix and just using the identity matrix however solves this problem and yields relatively nice results... The problem is that I do not really understand what I changed, and maybe I am doing something I should not be doing.

This is the code from the pyRiemann package I am using (modified to avoid using functions defined in other parts of the package):

```
# X are samples (EEG data), y are labels
# shape of X is (1000, 64, 2459)
# shape of y is (1000,)

from scipy.linalg import eigh

Ne, Ns, Nt = X.shape
tmp = X.transpose((1, 2, 0))
b = np.matrix(sklearn.covariance.empirical_covariance(tmp.reshape(Ne, Ns * Nt).T))

for c in self.classes_:
    # Prototyped response for each class
    P = np.mean(X[y == c, :, :], axis=0)

    # Covariance matrix of the prototyper response & signal
    a = np.matrix(sklearn.covariance.empirical_covariance(P.T))

    # Spatial filters
    evals, evecs = eigh(a, b)
    # and I am now using the following, disregarding the b matrix:
    # evals, evecs = eigh(a)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If A and B were both symmetric matrices that doesn't necessarily have to imply that inv(A)*B must be a symmetric matrix. And so, if i had to solve a generalised eigenvalue problem of Ax=lambda Bx then i would use eig(A,B) rather than eig(inv(A)*B), so that the symmetry isn't lost.

One practical application is in finding the natural frequencies of a dynamic mechanical system from differential equations of the form M (d²x/dt²) = Kx where M is a positive definite matrix known as the mass matrix and K is the stiffness matrix, and x is displacement vector and d²x/dt² is acceleration vector which is the second derivative of the displacement vector. To find the natural frequencies, x can be substituted with x0 sin(ωt) where ω is the natural frequency. The equation reduces to Kx = ω²Mx. Now, one can use `eig(inv(K)*M)` but that might break the symmetry of the resultant matrix, and so I would use `eig(K,M)` instead.

Comment: The first part made me curious. Do you mean that we can transform the general eigenvalue problem of symmetric matrices in a tridiagonal problem, just like the standard eigenvector problem? If you have a good material I would like to have a look :) thanks.

Comment: @Bob Firstly, sorry for the delay in my reply. And what I meant by my first paragraph is that the product of two symmetric matrices isn’t necessarily a symmetric matrix, and so, if there is an eigenvalue problem that is in the form A x = lambda B x, then reducing it to a normal eigenvalue problem would be to reduce it to inv(B) A x = lambda x, and if we assume inv(B) A = C, then it would become C x = lambda x, which is a normal eigenvalue problem, but here C doesn’t necessarily have to be symmetric.

Comment: @Bob And so, in order to solve the problem, we need to solve an eigenvalue problem that might be non-symmetric, even though the original matrices happened to be symmetric.

Here is a method (given in Section 7.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.11240.pdf)) in which the algorithm takes the symmetric matrices A and B (in which B is positive definite) as input, and the original problem can be solved by solving the eigenvalues of symmetric matrices alone, without taking the burden of solving the eigenvalues of non-symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 0):

`A - lambda B x` it means that x is not in the same basis as the covariance matrix.

If the matrix is not definite positive it means that there are vectors that can be flipped by your B.

I hope it was helpful.